# Is there a way to find why my Maven project does not acknowledge some classes?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I created a new Project which includes two different Maven projects.
One directory- common will hold some common classes and interfaces, the other directory - tests will hold all the tests.

Created a new class in common - Page.java.

Created a new class in tests - TestPage.java.

Now when trying to create an instance of Page inside TestPage class, the intellij marks it red.

**Notes**

1. Both of the projects have the same package name
2. In tests Maven project the pom.xml has a dependency of the common's pom.xml.

Thanks for the helpers !! (;

Comment: You need to name the directory for sources `src/main/java` and the one for tests `src/test/java`.

Comment: well each Maven project holds two directories - main and test.

Comment: So are they named and structured exactly as I said?

Comment: yes they are.
Common:    common/src/main/java/com/my_comp/testing/topics/pages/Page.java
Test:   tests/src/test/java/com/my_comp/testing/topics/TestPage.java

Comment: So how does your project "contain" the two different Maven projects? Is it a multi-module project? Does it have a POM at the root level that contains both projects as `<modules>` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't declare them as modules, in the root directory there are nor pom files, in each directory I hold a pom file. After running mvn clean install at the common directory the issue was resolved. @JFMeier thanks for the help!